# Can't upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to 14.04.1 LTS. It is showing:

```
You have to download a total of 137 k. This download will take about 
4 seconds with your connection. 

Installing the upgrade can take several hours. Once the download has 
finished, the process cannot be canceled. 

Continue [yN]  Details [d]d
Continue [yN]  Details [d]y

Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                    

Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have 
been kept. 

Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/libgcj-common_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_all.deb 
403 Forbidden 



Restoring original system state

Aborting...
```

Comment: You didn't state which command you are running for upgrading. Anyway, you could try to do the upgrade from the 14.04 live cd, it should work without problems.

Comment: try to upgrade using different server.

Comment: I'm using "do-release-upgrade" to upgrade .. everything went fine but at last it shows 403 forbidden .. and upgrade is aborted ...

Comment: See also [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's better to disable all third-party repositories, if you have.
Next you have to update your system with:

> **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get
>   dist-upgrade**

Then you have to run Update Manager through terminal to upgrade to 14.04.
Open a terminal and write this:

> **update-manager -d**

And you are ready to upgrade your distro to 14.04 ...!!!