# Can't Upgrade from 14.04.5-LTS to 16.04-LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, wine

Using the GUI Updater which has always showed "Upgrade available" but I have ignored it -- up until today. :) Then got the errors.

The only two packages that I am aware of are BackInTime (BiT) and Wine and both have their PPAs defined and checked. After the first go around of errors I disabled the PPAs for Wine and BiT and the ERROR1 message went away, but still got ERROR 2.

I tried this but same again...
[Can't upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512535/cant-upgrade-from-12-04lts-to-14-04lts)

How do I do the Upgrade?
OR, is there some way to push all my 14.04 programs and data over to a clean install of 16.04?

> ERROR 1: Preparing to Upgrade
>
> Third party sources disabled
>   Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.
>
> ERROR2: Setting new software channels
>
> Could not calculate the upgrade
>   An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>    This can be caused by:
>    * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
>    * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
>    * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Software and Updates" and click the "Other Software" tab. Deselect any PPAs there and try again.

Screenshots coming soon.

Comment: Thanks, bit do not worry about pics. I had already done that, mentioned _After the first go around of errors I disabled the PPAs for Wine and BiT and the ERROR1 message went away, but still got ERROR 2._